# Numerical methods to solve nonlinear boundary value ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I am dealing with a second order and a 10th order nonlinear differential equation. I want to solve these problems using the Petrov-Galerkin method, but for that I need to linearize the differential equations  first. How can I linearize a higher order nonlinear  ordinary differential equation to solve with the Petrov-Galerkin method? I have heard about the quasilinearization process developed by Bellman and Kalaba. Can anyone suggest me good resources to learn the quasilinearization process or show me the way to conduct the process?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answer to your problem will cost certainly depend on the details of your equations. It is not realistic that your question will receive an answer until you provide specific equations.